# C# how to extensively test parameters (with results converging to certain values)

Tags: c#, testing

I have C# program with 3 variables as an input (textboxes in my case). Based on this values, I run computation and get results, in my case 14 numbers. Thing is, that I already know from another source, how the results (this 14 numbers) should approximately look like and I am interested in answering the question:

```
With which input values do I get as close to results as possible?
```

Which leads me to trying all possibilities in a certain ranges, I guess. So my question is, is there any way how Visual studio can help me to do this? Or, how would YOU do it?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: Are you talking about testing from a unit testing perspective - or testing as in trying to find an optimal solution (e.g. a linear programming problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)

Answer (score 0):

I would probable used data driven test. It really depends on what unit test framework you are using. For example, in MStest, you can have your test values saved in Excel sheet and test will check all the values from Excel sheet.
Let's say:

```
# | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Expected
0 |    1   |   1    |    1   |   1
1 |    1   |   1    |    2   |   1
```

So you are writing just one test and it will automatically execute it multiple times (2 times in the example above). You can google for Data Driven Testing using your framework for details.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above this would depend on how you are planning on running these tests.

One option you could look at would be to use MBUnit, there are several mechanisms there to run tests against different numbers.

Take a look at http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit:documentation

I would suggest looking at the external data sources and potentially the `Factory` attribute